# ColdFusion 2018: How to setup a mapping correctly?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018, cfadmin

These are the steps I use:

1) I created new mapping inside CF Server => Server Settings => Mapping

```
logical path: /mysite
directory path: /Volumes/drive2/work/mysite
```

2) I restarted the server

```
/Applications/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion stop && /Applications/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion start
```

3) Using my preferred text editor, I created test.cfm inside /Volumes/drive2/work/mysite with the following contents

```
<cfdump var="#CGI#">
```

4) I then tried viewing the new file on my browser via

```
localhost:8500/mysite/test.cfm
```

I then get a 404 error. Exact message goes like "coldfusion.runtime.TemplateNotFoundException: File not found: /mysite/test.cfm"

I checked these 2 things:

1. I verified that /Volumes/drive2/work/mysite is readable by everyone (755 permission)
2. I verified that /Volumes/drive2/work/mysite/test.cfm  is readable by everyone (644 permission)

Other than creating the mapping, the other configurations I've changed are:

1. created datasource for my app
2. Enabled debugging/logging but only after I got the first 404 error

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? or perhaps other settings I should've set? I've added a screenshot of the mappings section below.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm using the built-in webserver provided by the standalone/developer edition. I'm also using localhost.

[image]

Comment: are you tried that in localhost or virtual host ? If it's virtual host then please follow the miguel-f answer. I mean you have to add alise in your web server.

Comment: Please see edited post. I am using localhost + developer edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is not what ColdFusion mappings are for.  ColdFusion mappings are used by ColdFusion code to access files.  What you are attempting to do via a request like `localhost:8500/mysite/test.cfm` is access a folder through your web server.  What you need to do for that is create a "virtual directory" using your web server admin.

You did not specify which web server you are using but it should be very easy to find documentation on how to accomplish what you need by searching your "web server name create virtual directory".

Here are a couple of examples for IIS and Apache.

[IIS Virtual Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory)

[Apache Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

If you are using the builtin Tomcat server, as we can assume by the use of localhost and port 8500, then follow the directions documented on the following page under the *Adding a virtual directory for ColdFusion using the built-in Tomcat application server* section.

[ColdFusion Tomcat](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-tomcat.html)

Comment: Port 8500 gives away, that they are using the the built in jetty (?) server.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the standalone/developer edition. I should've made that clear. Editing original post. Thanks